# Trouble when merging two arrays after getting checkbox values

Tags: php, arrays

I have many checkboxes with same name. They are devided with 2 names `subcategory` and `categories`.

So i have this code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['subcategory'])) 
{
    $SubCategorys[] = $_POST['subcategory'];
    $categories[] = $_POST['categories'];
    $MergedArrays = array_merge($SubCategorys, $categories);

    echo implode(",",$MergedArrays);


}
?>
```

I receive result like this:

```
Array,Array
```

I want to receive result like this: `"3, 6, 34, 65, 23, 67,"`.

Where is my mistake and how can i achive that goal ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you do an example for the `Array,Array` output?

Comment: I want output like this: `"3, 6, 34, 65, 23, 67,"`

Comment: instead of `echo`, use `var_dump($mergedArrays);`.  It will give you much more meaningful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['subcategory']` and `$_POST['categories']` are already arrays. You don't have to use external arrays in this case:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['subcategory'])) 
    {
        $SubCategorys = $_POST['subcategory'];
        $categories = $_POST['categories'];
        $MergedArrays = array_merge($SubCategorys, $categories);

        echo implode(",",$MergedArrays);

    }
    ?>
```

> Note: **implode** function lets you to join elements with a string in ONE-dimensional arrays only
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: You should highlight the key element you added: `implode` - and add a link to the PHP docs for `implode`.

Comment: @cale_b, why should I do that?

Comment: can you paste your html please ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - to make the answer valuable to the people who find this question / answer later.  Or don't.  Whatever you want, it's your answer.

Comment: @Roman i am not joking , i need to see how the checkboxes has values .

Comment: one up.  it's a better answer now.  Thanks!

Comment: @cale_b, Thank's a lot, buddy! )

Answer (score 0):

you should use store them in a variable with implode method

```php
$hobby = $_POST['game'];
$b = implode(",", $hobby);
```

Comment: and then in values use b